# The command '\bin\javaw.exe' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have downloaded my grails project from SVN and tried to run it.Project Using grails 2.0.4 version.I'm using STS 3.0 version.I have set the JAVA_HOME properly and added the proper grails compiler in the STS.

When i try to run the project it throws the following error and build not starting up

The command '\bin\javaw.exe' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I had the same problem with GGTS based on Eclipse Juno 4.2.1. If you try with Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0.RELEASE - based on Eclipse Juno 3.8.1 it should work.

Comment: Tried in GGTS 3.1.0 based on Eclipse 3.8.1. Still getting the same error

Comment: Im using older version of Windows XP machine. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem related with the way Grails executes multiple commands through a single external process. If you are in Eclipse (+GGTS plugin), go to "Windows > Preferences > Groovy > Grails > Grails Launch", then disable the "Keep External Grails Running" option.

Answer (score 2):

This is also happening in GGTS.

My workaround to this is to create Run Configuration. Open Run Configurations, double click Grails, it will create new Grails configuration. Rename it, select your project and enter grails command: run-app. Click Apply or Run.

On the top toolbar where you have run configurations drop-down, it should include your new configuration. Running this way will not timeout.

This STS issue is [kinda-related](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135631-GGTS-3-2-Consoles-not-terminating-with-Grails-2-2-1). Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Grails Launch is the place where you can find all the options.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem when I tried to use `run-app` from the `grails command line`.  Try using the `Run menu` instead.

**Run** -> **Run As** -> **Grails Command (run-app)**

See [this ticket](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3194).

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem when I try run war on my project. I fixed it by change setting in

Windows -> Preference -> Groovy -> Grails -> Grails Launch -> Grails Command Timeout[ms]

Change the timeout time to a big value.